# NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to remove last two value from array. So, i used to do below code -

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *resMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *responseData = [resMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (responseData != nil) 
    {

        array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

        if([array count] == 2) {

        }else
        {
             int k = [self.array count] -2 ;
             int l = [self.array count] -1 ;

             [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:l];
             [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:k];

             [gridTable reloadData];
             [tblProducts reloadData];
         }

    }

}
```

But, its giving below exception -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

I don't know why this happened? I've already used this method in another viewController class too. It was working fine there. But, here its giving exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned from `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];` will return an autoreleased `NSArray`.  If you want to make it mutable, you'll have to call `NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];`

Your other option here is instead of putting in a 0 for your `options:` parameter, put `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.  This will solve your problem without creating an extra object.

**EDIT**

In order to fix your new problem:

```
NSMutableArray *newData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
//Here, modify the new array.  Remove your last two items. Then..
[newData addObjectsFromArray:array];
array = newData;
```

As a side note, this may cause you to have your array objects in a different order than you expect.  You may choose to call this...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES];
array = [newData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: Or use `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.

Comment: So, i've to remove those two values from `mutableArray` which is copy of array?

Comment: @mattjgalloway Was just going to add that as well :)

Comment: @SpK Yes, or you can take mattjgalloway's suggestion and instead of passing 0 in your options, you can pass the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option.

Comment: @mattjgalloway But, its removing my old records when i try both ways :(

Comment: What do you mean it's removing your old records?

Comment: @SpK That's probably because you're replacing your old array with the array from the JSON data.

Comment: No. There i've to add my new records. How do i do that?

Comment: @mattjgalloway Its removing my old array values. And, adding new values there.

Comment: @SpK So, I'm assuming before this connection is done, you're using `array` as the datasource for your table.  This line, `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];` is replacing your array.  The old array is gone at this point.  If you want to fix this...I'll just edit my answer.

Comment: Yes. Am using that `array` as my table's datasource.

Comment: Its shuffling my records. So, thats why you're telling to use that `NSSortDescriptor?` And the warning `incompatiable pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *_strong' from nsarray` raised.

Comment: @SpK Yes, that's why I suggested using the `NSSortDescriptor`.  As far as the warning goes, you might be assigning your `array` to a NSMutableArray, which you can't.  The code I have above shouldn't display that warning (that I know of.  Not currently on my mac, so I can't confirm).